# Need to access native interface code (android paypal integration) from codename one

Tags: android, paypal, codenameone

I have write some paypal integration code with android under native interface Impl.I have copied the paypal SDK and android-support-v4 under native/android folder. Can anyone please help with the required android.xapplication and android.xpermissions.
need to include the below entries:

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> 
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
<categoryandroid:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
<serviceandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"android:exported="false"/> 
<activityandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity"/> 
<activityandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity"/> 
<activityandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity"/> 
<activityandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity"/> 
<activityandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity"/> 
<activityandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity"/> 
<activityandroid:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity"/> 
<activityandroid:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity"/>
```

getting build error java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build6857927875990546701xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for entry codename1.arg.android.xapplication in codenameone_settings.
It is successfully build with the entry

```
codename1.arg.android.xapplication\==<service android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"android\:exported\="false"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity"/>
```

But not found the PaymentActivity class from paypal sdk jar while testing from device. Can you please help on that.

Comment: Hi  priyanka 
can  you pls add your source codes of paypal?

Comment: Its a long code and I don't know How to attach a file here.But I am facing problem which I maintained here.Let me know how to attach a java file here.will share the code.

Comment: can you email me on my email
tizbnandroid@gmail.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Internet permission is already added by default by codenameone so need to ask for it.
2. The android-support-v4 is also added by default so no need to add it.

In the [build hints settings UI](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) set:

```
android.xapplication=<service android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"android:exported="false"/> 
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity"/> 
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity"/> 
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity"/> 
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity"/> 
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity"/> 
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity"/> 
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity"/> 
<activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity"/>

android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Or alternatively open your `codenameone_settings.properties` and add the following:

```
codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<service android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"android\:exported\="false"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity"/>  <activity android\:name\="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity"/>



codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Edited to escape the properties instructions

Comment: Hello,I have edited the question and posted a new problem.please help me to solve that.